# C Pointers and Multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I am trying to write a program that requests the first and last names of a group of people (say a class of students). The first names are put into a multidimensional array and the last names are also put into a different multidimensional array. The while loops I used to get the students names call a function that replaces any '\n' with a '\0'. After the arrays are filled, they get assigned to a pointer. <--I think I said that right. I can't get the while loops to keep requesting student's names. I need to be able to input up to 30 names.

```
printf("Input student %d first name.\n",G);
printf("To stop, press the Enter key at a line's start.\n");
while (ct < LIM && s_gets(firstNames[ct], SIZE) != NULL
       && firstNames[ct][0] != '\0')
{
    first[ct] = firstNames[ct];  
    ct++;
    printf("Input student %d last name, and I will sort them.\n",G);
    while (ct2 < ct && s_gets(lastNames[ct2], SIZE) != NULL
        && lastNames[ct2][0] != '\0')
    {
    last[ct2] = lastNames[ct2];  
    ct2++;
    G++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second loop is _inside_ the first loop.

Comment: ^^^ e.g. you'll be prompting for last name for *every* character of the first name. Find [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and explain your code, line by line, loop by loop, to him. He'll tell you what is wrong without saying a word.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug your code.   The posted code fails to show the declarations of the variables, nor the arrays, nor indicates what `s_gets()` does

Comment: I apologize if I posted incorrectly. This is my first post. I need to do some research on the required formatting because when I tried to post the whole program, the site would not allow it due to formatting.